# Angular4 : Router not working. routing error: Error: no elements in sequence

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have specified url with some of below pattern.

- streamz/abc
- streamz/search/xyz
- streamz/abc/123

For that I created router like below.

```
{ path: 'streamz/:name', loadChildren: './streamz-message/streamz-message.module#StreamzMessageModule' },
{ path: 'streamz/search/:id', loadChildren: './streamz-search/streamz-search.module#StreamzSearchModule' },
{ path: 'streamz/:brand/:id', loadChildren: './streamz-detail/streamz-detail.module#StreamzDetailModule' },
```

This is working fine till yesterday. Once I am installing new node_modules this is not working. This is throwing error as below.

> router-error-handling.ts:12 routing error:  Error: no elements in sequence
>       at new EmptyError (EmptyError.js:27)
>       at FirstSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/first.js.FirstSubscriber._complete (first.js:154)
>       at FirstSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:121)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._complete (mergeMap.js:144)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:121)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._complete (Subscriber.js:139)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:121)
>       at EmptyObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable.js.EmptyObservable._subscribe (EmptyObservable.js:82)
>       at EmptyObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:173)
>       at EmptyObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:161)
>   CustomRoutingExtraOptions.errorHandler @ router-error-handling.ts:12
>   (anonymous) @ router.es5.js:4194
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
>   onInvoke @ core.es5.js:3890
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
>   (anonymous) @ zone.js:831
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
>   onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:3881
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
>   drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
>   webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
>   invokeTask @ zone.js:1364
>   globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1382

Whats wrong with above routing pattern. Kindly help.

Comment: Apparently it's a recent 5.5.3 rxjs bug. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3151 ppl been panicking since yesterday

Comment: @ChauTran I was sure this is due to some library upgrade but not aware about specific library. I will try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this error as well. It's caused by the bug in RxJS 5.5.3.  I've changed the RxJS dependency to be as follows:

```
"rxjs": "5.5.2"
```

This fixed the issue.